# Is the keyword "STDOUT" ruby- or cygwin-specific in this command?

Tags: ruby, cygwin, stdout

The following command which you can use in the cygwin console to output text in this console.

```
ruby -e 'STDOUT << "ABC" << " DEF"'
```

My question is: the **STDOUT** part is a ruby keyword or a cygwin keyword? How can I use it? Great thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`STDOUT` is a Ruby global constant. It is an instance of the [`IO`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/IO.html) class that outputs to standard output stream. `$>` and `$stdout` are references to the same `IO` instance.

In your example, you are calling the [`<<`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/IO.html#M002277) method of `IO`, which writes out the argument and then returns itself.

Answer (score 1):

`STDOUT` is a pre-defined global constant in Ruby. You can also use `$stdout` or `$>`.